# How to exclude files from merge in Git?

Tags: git, merge

Suppose I merge a branch to the master. Since I do not want to merge *everything*  I run `git merge --no-commit`, check merged files manually, and decide to exclude some of them from the merge. So, I run `git reset HEAD <file>` and `git checkout <file>` for every file I want to exclude from the merge.

Does it make sense? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work. You can also checkout each file from the version where you were:

```
git checkout HEAD -- <a list of the files you want to not change>
```

Why, may I ask, do you need to do this?

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to execute `git reset HEAD <file>` before `git checkout <file>`. The single `git checkout <file>` will do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it can also work for directories, as in [this thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Merging-back-from-master-but-keeping-a-subtree-td6803458.html):

```
git checkout HEAD -- top/middle/mydirectory
```

would restore all the files within '`mydirectory`'