# github codeowners for each branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, github-codeowners

Github says I can assign different code owners for different branch.
but how?
Is there any way for having different file for different branch without any conflict on merging??

please let me know how I can do it.

https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners#codeowners-file-location

> Each CODEOWNERS file assigns the code owners for a single branch in the repository. Thus, you can assign different code owners for different branches, such as @octo-org/codeowners-team for a code base on the default branch and @octocat for a GitHub Pages site on the gh-pages branch.

Comment: Do you really need to merge branches with different code owners for the same files into each other? If so, why? This kind of feels like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2):

> Github says I can assign different code owners for different branch.
> but how?

Exactly that — by having different files in different branches.

> Is there any way for having different file for different branch without any conflict on merging??

Well, no. But you can configure **your local repository** to work around the conflicts.

First, you can use [builtin merge driver](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_performing_a_three_way_merge) "ours"; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59503455/7976758 found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+exclude+file+merge

```
echo .github/CODEOWNERS merge=ours >> .gitattributes
git config merge.ours.driver true
```

This doesn't completely exclude the file from merge but lower the frequency of conflicts. If you want to completely exclude it and always update it manually you [can do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7475093/7976758)

```
git checkout HEAD .github/CODEOWNERS
```

after merge. You can try to automate this in a [`post-merge` hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge). Something like

```bash
echo '#! /bin/sh
git checkout HEAD .github/CODEOWNERS
' > .git/hooks/post-merge
chmod u+x .git/hooks/post-merge
```