# How protect and keep CODEOWNERs of a Github branch?

Tags: git, github

I found an issue using CODEOWNERS mechanism with multiple branches. Imagine if a repository has  “master” and “release” branches . In “master” branch "userM" and in “release” branch "userR" is code owner of repository. And we never want to change code owners of those branches.

| Branch | Code Owner before merge to master | Code Owner after merge to master |
| --- | --- | --- |
| release | * @userR | * @userR |
| master | * @userM | * @userR |

When we merge release into master branch, code owner of master branch will be overwritten by code owner of release branch and both become userR. How can we protect and keep code owner of a branch while merging other branches to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [github codeowners for each branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75380368/github-codeowners-for-each-branch)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571881/1725151

Comment: Personally I would use separate files for each branch so that I don’t have to deal with this complexity.

Comment: @Guildenstern The file has fixed path and name — it's always `.github/CODEOWNERS`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53824365/7976758